# online marketplace - what is the usual image size allowed? Right now we have 500MB is this too small?

Tags: image, magento, size

Creating an online marketplace on Magento - users are having problems with uploading pic size of 500KB is this too small?  Should we allow larger images, or will this slow down site?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JPG compression by default. That should allow you to get big enough file sizes (e.g. 1440 x 900 should well be possible depending on the color variation etc.) at file sizes less then 500 KB.

For images with little color variation, PNG will be a better choice, but you cant really decide that automatically, so just allowing JPG would be an option. However, your users might not find that helpful, so you might consider actually using a JPG compression lib in your service.

Its really just a matter of user habits and convenience. Personally, i compress and scale down my image files to a reasonable size. It comes down to whether you want your users to do that, or do it for them, or just weaken the size limit.

In any case, 1 MB should definitely be sufficient, although many sites nowadays allow file sizes up to 5 MB.